# Jquery, getting back list of ID strings of all elements with ID's that "begin with" a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I'm not a Javascript guru as I do more server-side work so am struggling with this. I have found bits and pieces of how to do this. Basically, I have a series of elements that have ids beginning with the string "tagRow_" and I need to get back a list of all of the actual element ids as I need not just the element but also the element's id as I need to parse the unique ending for each on the server-side to determine what it corresponds to.

I found the code below to get all elements but am not sure what it is returning as far as a list or what, if anyone can offer advice how to return just a list of string id names I would appreciate it. Thanks

**EDIT: I actually need to do this with a radio input field, it was by mistake I put a DIV in my own example. It works fine for a DIV but is not working properly for a radio input like below:**

```
 <input id="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="h">
                <input id="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="p">
                    <input id="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="r">
                    <input id="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="c">

$("input[id^='tagRow_']").each(function() {

   var id = this.id,
       idNumber = id.replace(/\D+/, '');
   document.body.innerHTML += idNumber + '<br />';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fD7fP/3/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/McyCF/2/)**

```
var elements = [];

$("div[id^='tagRow_']").each(function(){
   elements.push(this.id); 
});

var stringOfElementIDs = elements.toString();
```

Comment: actually I am trying with an Input field, I made a mistake in OP, seems it doesn't work the same way for some reason as a DIV

Comment: @Rick try this http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/McyCF/4/ your looking for digits, so if you leave _ddd on the end it wont find the numbers, so in the fiddle I changed the _ddd to numbers.

Answer (score 22):

Try the following:

```
var ids = $("div[id^='tagRow_']").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

This returns an array of all the IDs. More information from this post: [Use jQuery to extract data from HTML lists and tables](https://web.archive.org/web/20160514083105/http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/).

Comment: ARH!! There's a difference between $(elem).map(callback(index, domElement)) and jQuery.map(array, callback(elementOfArray, indexInArray)): On the $(elem).map() page [ api.jquery.com/map/ ] it says: "Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values. [...] If you wish to process a plain array or object, use the jQuery.map() instead."

Comment: +1 I prefer this solution, as you're not using closures to get the ids.

Comment: `const ids = $('[id]').get().map(elem => elem.id);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div[id^=tagRow_]").each()....
```

example:

```
$("div[id^='tagRow_']").each(function() {    
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number on the client side too.

```
$("div[id^='tagRow_']").each(function() {

   var id = this.id,
       idNumber = id.replace(/\D+/, '');

   // idNumber contains the digits that were in the id

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fD7fP/).

Answer (score 0):

That will return a list of matching DOM elements (as jQuery objects). So you will have to loop through it and put the ids in a separate array.

```
var matching_els = $("div[id^='tagRow_']"), ids = [];
for(var i=0; i<matching_els.length; i++){
  ids.push(matching_els[i].attr("id");
}
// send ids back to server
```

Comment: You have a missing ) after .attr("id")